Azure container error ADF: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: Operation failed: "Server failed to authenticate the request
I am trying to connect file in the Azure blob container from Azure Data Factory, but it's throwing the following error:
at Source 'source2': java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: Operation failed:
"Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of  
Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.", 403, HEAD,   Azure Data Factory
https://heiaep****1.dfs.core.windows.net/**containerName**/?upn=false&action=getAccessControl&timeout=90"  


what authorization are you using in ADF linked service? can you provide linked service configurations? and error image as well? I mean are you getting the above error while connecting to linked service or while executing the pipeline?

@rakesh-govindula I am using storage account key authentication type. Thank you , I rotated the keys for storage account and updated with new keys , its working .

Good to know your issue got resolved. Posting the same as answer for anyone searching for solution for similar issue.
